# Definition of "expression"

Tags: java

In my Java book, it says that "an expression is a statement that can convey a return value." This is different than my traditional understanding. I thought an expression DOES return a value. Not CAN return a value.

this is from Sams Teach Yourself Java in 21 Days.

Comment: There are lots of other confusing parts to this book. I think in a very literal and technical manner, so I despise any technical writings that leave room for ambiguity.

Comment: any `Teach Yourself in N Days` book is suspect, get a better book, what year was that book printed?

Comment: The book is actually correct.  See my answer.  (Not that I'd ever recommend a "Teach yourself XXX" or "XXX for Dummies" book as a good way to learn a programming language.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mathematical expression always returns something, but a Java expression doesn't have to. The Java Specification defines [what exactly is meant by the term expression in the Java language](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html). Another difference is that expressions can, and often do, have side effects in Java. A side effect is pretty much anything that happens *other* than returning a value.

Quoting the Java Language Specification:

> Much of the work in a program is done by evaluating expressions, either for their side effects, such as assignments to variables, or for their values, which can be used as arguments or operands in larger expressions, or to affect the execution sequence in statements, or both.

For example `system.out.println("Hello World");` doesn't return a value, but it does print `Hello World` to the output stream. This process of outputting data is a side effect of calling `println`. [Functional languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), in contrast, attempt to minimize dependence on side effects and stick more closely to the mathematical definition of an expression.

[Quoting from the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#23302) again, here is the [BNF grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) for an expression:

```
Primary:
    PrimaryNoNewArray
    ArrayCreationExpression

PrimaryNoNewArray:
    Literal
    Type . class 
    void . class 
    this
    ClassName.this
    ( Expression )
    ClassInstanceCreationExpression
    FieldAccess
    MethodInvocation
    ArrayAccess
```

You can see that a [`MethodInvocation`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#20448) is an expansion of `PrimaryNoNewArray`, which is an expansion of `Primary` (expression).

Comment: wouldn't system.out.println("whatever"); be considered a statement? i know that expressions are also considered statements, but i thought they also returned something.

Comment: system.out.println() is a `MethodInvocation` which is a `PrimaryNoNewArray` which is a `Primary`. [Statements](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/statements.doc.html#32584) are another thing entirely. Please don't get hung up on the similarity in terminology between Java and math. The JLS defines its terms very carefully!

Comment: Please see my Answer for a rebuttal.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is incomplete.  In Java, an expression *could* return a value, and it *could* terminate due to an exception.  Similar situations arise in other languages which support exceptions, and more generally.  (For instance, in the C language, division by zero causes the current expression evaluation to terminate without returning a value.)

---

Another explanation is that (according to the JLS), a method invocation expression like `System.err.println("hello")` can deliver a notional `void` value to its context, and this really means that it is delivering no value.

I don't think this second explanation is sound.  We start with an "expression" that is specified as delivering a void value.  Then we are argue that since the void value is in reality not a value, the expression is delivering nothing.   Finally, we say it is an expression that delivers no value.

A simpler explanation for this example is that an "expression" that delivers "void" is not really an expression in the intuitive sense.  Certainly, in Java you cannot use a void-delivering MethodInvocation expression where a non-void-delivering expression is required.  And you can't use a non-void-delivering expression as a Statement.

Alternatively, we can stick with the JLS treatment and say that the "void" value really is a value ... even though you can't ever do anything with it.  By this argument,  `System.err.println("Hi")` *is* returning a value after all.

Comment: it actually says "can *convey* a value." maybe that makes more sense.

Comment: @Micheal - the problem is with your "traditional" understanding, not with the book.

Answer (score 0):

The method `public void foo();` does not return anything, thus the expression `foo()` does not return anything. But if the method was `public int foo()`, then it would. Thus it *could* return something, but doesn't necessarily have to. [From the Java spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#229523):

> An expression denotes nothing if and only if it is a method invocation
>   that invokes a method that does not return a value, that is, a method
>   declared void. Such an expression can be used only as an expression
>   statement, because every other context in which an expression can
>   appear requires the expression to denote something. An expression
>   statement that is a method invocation may also invoke a method that
>   produces a result; in this case the value returned by the method is
>   quietly discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch...  This doesn't seem like a very good book :(

An expression either has a type and can be evaluated to yield a value of that type, or is of `void` type and can be evaluated to yield nothing.  The [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html) also says an expression can evaluate to a variable, but the variable in turn has a type and a value.  For example, `1 + 1` is an expression.

A statement, on the other hand, is composed of expressions but doesn't have a type or a value itself.  For example, `int x = 1 + 1;` has no value.  It wouldn't make sense in Java to say something like `System.out.println(int x = 1 + 1;);`